# How to update a status field based on any field change in a record using process builder?

Tags: process-builder, field-update

How to update a status field based on any field change in a record using process builder ??

Currently i have a process builder which updated the status based on value change in field_A Or Field_B, now i want the functionality like updated the statues based on the values change in any field in my record.

Any one can help with above scenario.

Comment: So you want a record to be always updated, regardless of the modified field?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Yes

Answer (score 0):

On process builder there's an option of "No criteria—just execute the actions!". It is on the step in which you define the criteria for an action group. By checking this option, the specified actions will always be executed for your records.

If this is needed on update only, then use the formula criteria with `NOT(ISNEW())`.

Comment: Yes, but if i use your solution it will also update the statues for new record also.here my scenario is only when update the record(Any field) we need to update the status

Comment: Then use the formula criteria with `NOT(ISNEW())` as parameter.